# Why is $2\mathbf{\hat{k}}\times \mathbf{\hat{j}} = -2\mathbf{\hat{i}}$?

Tags: vectors

Why is   $2\mathbf{\hat{k}}\times \mathbf{\hat{j}} = -2\mathbf{\hat{i}}$?

How do we do it?

Please tell how to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Can you tell how did you approach this problem? How much you know about cross products? If you tell us your efforts, then we may tell you where you go wrong.

Comment: Exactly which part about this is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @infinity_hunter You have to put the `\hat` in front of what you want a hat on. Not after. So `\hat i` or `\hat{i}` give $\hat i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\vec {2k} \times \vec j = 2(\vec {k} \times \vec j)=2(-\vec{i})=-2\vec i$$

Comment: @Anonymous I provided this because I thought that the OP might not be aware of the fact that you can pull out a scalar while multiplying (both dot and cross)